# Behavior Subject not Updating Async Pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject, subject

I'm trying to use a behavior subject to feed an async pipe in my html. The subject works on the initial load but then will not register the emit on any subsequent attempt to update it. What I cannot figure out is why next on the behavior subject is not triggering apiCall() from the switchMap.

buy-plans.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="buyPlan$ | async as buyPlan; else loading">
     <div class="desktop-container" *ngIf="deviceInfoService.isDesktopDevice; else mobileContainer">
         <app-buy-plans-desktop [buyPlan]="buyPlan"> </app-buy-plans-desktop>
     </div>
     <ng-template #mobileContainer>
         <app-buy-plans-mobile [buyPlan]="buyPlan"></app-buy-plans-mobile>
     </ng-template>
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
      <div class="spinner-wrapper" [ngClass]="{ 'sidenav-open': sharedService.isSidenavOpen$ | async }">
          <div class="spinner-mask"></div>
              <mat-spinner class="buy-plans-spinner" color="accent"></mat-spinner>
          </div>
</ng-template>
```

buyplans.component.ts

```
export class BuyPlansComponent implements OnInit {
  buyPlanSub$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  buyPlan$ = new Observable<ICollectionDto | IErrorDto>();
  testSub$ = new Subject();

  title = '';
  creationDate = '';
  progressSpinnerMode = 'indeterminate';
  createDialogData: IModifyBuyPlanDialogVM = {
    title: 'Create Buy Plan',
    primaryAction: {
      buttonColor: 'accent',
      text: 'Create'
    }
  };

  constructor(
    private collectionService: CollectionService,
    private buyPlanService: BuyPlanService,
    public sharedService: SharedService,
    public deviceInfoService: DeviceInfoService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buyPlan$ = this.buyPlanSub$.pipe(switchMap(e => this.apiCall(e)));

    // testSub$ is extraneous and just for debugging that I could get an emit out of the subscribe
    this.testSub$.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('Test Sub Hit'); //Reaches here
      this.buyPlanSub$.next({}); // Does not go to apiCall()
    });

    this.buyPlanSub$.next(null);
  }

  apiCall(id) {
    console.log('In API call');
    return this.collectionService.get(null, CollectionItemType.BuyPlan);
  }

  cancelBuyPlan(id: number) {}

  copyBuyPlan(id: number) {}

  deleteBuyPlan(id: number) {
    this.buyPlanService.delete(id).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.testSub$.next(response);
    });
  }

  openCreateBuyPlanDialog($event) {}
}
```

Comment: Could you please narrow down... remove code not adding to the problem? What definitely looks suspicious is that you initialise `buyPlan$` twice... `buyPlan$ = new Observable<ICollectionDto | IErrorDto>();` and `this.buyPlan$ = this.buyPlanSub$.pipe(switchMap(e => this.apiCall(e)));` in NgOnInit.

Comment: Yeah, that's extraneous from swapping the type. However, I don't think it's the problem as the switchMap is causing it to re-emit on the first API call. The subsequent calls are where the issue occurs.

Comment: You have no subscription to buyPlan$ observable

Comment: That's what the *ngIf="buyPlan$ | async" is for. Angular manages the subscribe/unsubscribe logic for you if you use the async pipe. It's really the best practice. It gets data to the screen, just no updates, which wouldn't be the case if it did not subscribe.

Comment: Where is your data comming from? You are shuffling data between observable that i think can be ommited. See my first answer. I will update once I know where your buyPlan is comming from - I guess it comes from one method within a injected service.

Comment: It comes from this.collectionService.get

Comment: Well its hard to notice on mobile browser that there is an async pipe. What i would suggest is to subscribe explicitly assign a property in that subscription and bind ngIf to that property. May be async pipe prevents ngIf to get change notifications because ubderlying subscription object doesnt change

Comment: Please tell a bit more in detail what the services provide and what you want to display... remember you almost never need a subscribe within Typescript. You can use Tap, Map, MergeMap, combineLatest, of etc. to alter the transfered data within the Pipe  or combine / split Pipes and finally load in HTML through Async-Pipe.